# What is the maximum file size that will be cached by a browser?

Tags: http, cache

What is the maximum file size that will be cached by a browser?  Note that I *don't* mean the maximum size of the browser cache.  I mean, what is the maximum individual file that will be cached.

If there is a limit, where is this documented?

Answer (score 5):

On firefox it looks like the maximum size is 5MB or whatever you have set for `browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size`.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=647391

Comment: what about other browsers?

Comment: @paleozogt Which browsers and which versions? Do you want to include "mobile" browsers as well?  You may be better served by testing your browsers with something like [Max Cache File Size](http://stevesouders.com/tests/cachesize/).

Comment: @jscott, neat tool, I think you should provide that as an answer.

Comment: FYI, using that tool on the current Windows version of chrome shows a max size of 8MB.

Comment: @jscott I was looking for some docs, but a tool to experimentally get the value is better. I agree with Zoredache that this is an answer!